# How to safely unpack an arbitrary single-value data structure (list, tuple, set, ...)?

Tags: python, containers, sequence, iterable

Sometimes I want to make sure a sequence or set-like data structure (e.g. a list, tuple or set, or any compatible user-defined data structure type) contains exactly one element and then use that element, but have the code rise an Error if there's less or more elements than exactly that one.

A naive approach is

```
def unpack_single(elements):
    assert len(elements) == 1, f"expected exactly 1 element, found {len(elements)} elements"
    return elements[0]
```

This works for lists and tuples:

```
>>> unpack_single([5])
5

>>> unpack_single((42,))
42

>>> unpack_single([])  # fails as expected
AssertionError: expected exactly 1 element, found 0 elements

>>> unpack_single(tuple())  # fails as expected
AssertionError: expected exactly 1 element, found 0 elements

>>> unpack_single([23, "foo"])  # fails as expected
AssertionError: expected exactly 1 element, found 2 elements

>>> unpack_single(tuple("foobar"))  # fails as expected
AssertionError: expected exactly 1 element, found 6 elements
```

But it **doesn't work for sets**, which aren't subscriptable:

```
>>> unpack_single({"wat"})  # fails, but I want this to work, too!
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

The alternative

```
def unpack_single(elements):
    assert len(elements) == 1, f"expected exactly 1 element, found {len(elements)} elements"
    return elements.pop()
```

does work for sets, but does **not work for tuples and frozensets**, as those aren't mutable and don't implement a `pop()` method.

An elegant but maybe a bit more obscure way to get this working is to use unpacking (destructuring assignment) to a length-1 variable list:

```
def unpack_single(elements):
    only_element, = elements
    return only_element
```

This works fine for lists, tuples, sets, frozensets and even for non-container iterables like `range` or `itertools.takewhile`. (And even for non-finite ones like `itertools.count`, as it *correctly* reports "too many values to unpack" for those.)

Though I fear that last approach is hard to understand for readers of the code. **Are there any better approaches that don't require external third-party dependencies?** Maybe even something the standard library offers?

Comment: What makes you think the last approach is too difficult to understand?

Comment: I didn't read the last part only_element, = elements looks like a good solution

Comment: @SebastianGaweda I dunno. _I_ understand it fine, but I thought that might just be because I came up with it myself. Does it convey the intention (fail if there's an unexpected number of elements) sufficiently clearly? If so, I think it'd be fine indeed.

Comment: Btw., as I do have a working solution, just don't know how "good" it is, is Stack Overflow the right place to ask this quesion or should I have asked at [codereview.SE]?

Comment: I think Code Review would be more appropriate for this question as qualifying a "better" approach is difficult in this case. I find your solution to be the simplest minimal implementation of what you wanted to accomplish and easily readable, but that's an opinion that not everyone who reads it may hold. I'd be surprised if you could show me another code snippet and convince me that it is an improved implementation.

Comment: Well, I was (and am) mostly wondering whether the standard library already has this functionality as a single function (maybe implemented the way of my last apporach, maybe built-in) that just does this, and I'm just failing to locate it in the Python documentation. If it did, just calling that standard library function would arguably be yet simpler and cleaner.

Comment: I've now asked a [corresponding (though slightly differently framed) question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/240718/70468) on [codereview.SE] and might delete the question here on [SO].

Comment: Seems like I'm not the only one who came up with the unpacking-into-singleton-tuple approach: [YouTube video _Python Weirdness - The comma equals ,= operator?_](https://youtu.be/KeIMUw22SZ8) by  mCoding

Answer (score 1):

Try `next(iter(elements))` maybe?

```
def unpack_single(elements):
    assert len(elements) == 1, f"expected exactly 1 element, found {len(elements)} elements"
    return next(iter(elements))
```